# How to set the text format of a field in a node object?

Tags: 8, nodes, entities

When I create a node like this:

```
$nodeSetup = [
  'nid' => NULL,
  'type' => $bundle,
  'uid' => $uid,
  'revision' => 0,
  'status' => 1,
  'body' => ['format' => 'full_html', 'value' => Xss::filter($body)],
];
$_node = Node::create($nodeSetup);
```

the body value and format work fine. But, when I load an existing node, how can I set the body value keeping the format? This didnt work:

```
$_node->body->format = 'full_html';
$_node->body->set('format', 'full_html');
$_node->save();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following worked for me,

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
$node->body->value = 'body';
$node->body->format = 'full_html';//omitting this will retain existing format
$node->save();
```

Comment: `$node->body->format = 'full_html';` didnt work for me. But, when the node was created with that format in the first place, `$node->body->value = 'body';` works. But using the `->set()` function seems to overwrite the format setting. Very strange and 0 documented...

Comment: @Alex, the answer seems OK to me, you can set properties of the field one at a time. `set()` is applied on the entity, not the field. If you want to set a field, use `setValue()` to set all properties at once and for this you provide an array (like you did already when creating the node).

Answer (score 5):

Kstack's solution works. Another option is to supply the value and format together in an array like so:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load(1);
$node->body->setValue(['value' => 'body', 'format' => 'full_html']);
$node->save();
```